# How to use count(*) WHERE IN in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `product` where barcode in (681155,
681144,
681145,
681146,
681147,
681148,
688123,
688124,
688125,
688126) GROUP BY(barcode);
```

how to use count(*) for this statement? I get 1 for all the rows

Comment: And what do you want to get as a result?

Comment: What do you mean? If `barcode` is unique, and you are grouping by it, you'll get a COUNT of `1` for each row, as expected.

Comment: Please show an extract of your table and what you actually expect as a result

Comment: @zerkms  I NEED THE RESULT AS 5

Comment: @soul: uhm, as what? o_O

Comment: @soul: Why 5? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Replace "count(*)" with 5 then.

Comment: @JoãoSilva because only 5 rows with that barcodes are present!! got the answer just need to remove group by

Comment: @soul: If you remove the group by, you'll get a count of 10, not 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `product` 
where barcode in
 (681155,
681144,
681145,
681146,
681147,
681148,
688123,
688124,
688125,
688126)
```

This will give you total count from the table

When you use GROUP BY it will take count for each group.

```
SELECT barcode ,COUNT(*) FROM `product` 
    where barcode in (....)
Group by barcode
```

If you get one for all rows, then your table contains distinct barcode

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the total count for all records just remove `GROUP BY` then. `GROUP BY` basically grouped the `Barcode` from each other that's why you are getting only one count for eact `barcode`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the GROUP BY(barcode) from your query and run. It should work for you.